# Comparison of $\operatorname{lim sup}$ and $\operatorname{lim inf}$ of two related sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{1/n}=1$. Initially, I failed to give elementary proof of this. I used a "theorem" which is an inequality, stated below, to prove this.

I came across the following inequality in real analysis: given a sequence $(x_n)$ of positive reals, we have

$$\lim \inf \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \leq \lim \inf x_n{}^{1/n}\leq \lim \sup {x_n}^{1/n}\leq \lim \sup \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}.$$

In particular,

(*) $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ exists $\displaystyle\Longrightarrow\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {x_n}^{1/n}$ exists (with same value).

**Question:** Is the converse of $(*)$ true? Also, I would like to see elementary proof of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{1/n}=1.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the converse is not true.Consider $x_n=\frac{1}{2} ;n$even and $x_n=\frac{1}{3} ;n $ odd

For the second one:

When $n=1$ result holds

$n>1$ then $n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1+h_n$

$\implies  n=(1+h_n)^n=1+nh_n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}h_n^2+...>\frac{n(n-1)}{2}h_n^2$

$\implies h_n^2<\frac{2}{n-1}$

$\implies h_n\rightarrow 0 as n\rightarrow \infty$

Thus limit is $1$

Comment: Is the sequence $\{n^{1/n}\}$ monotonic?

Comment: yes it is so,monotonic  decreasing

Comment: Can you give me a hint to prove this monotonicity?

Comment: yes sure $x^\frac{1}{x}$ is monotonically decreasing for $x>0$

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $\;\{\sqrt[n]n\}\;$  is monotonic decreasing for $\;n\ge 3\;$ , but in any case we can write

$$\sqrt[n]n\ge1\implies \sqrt[n]n=1+c_n\;,\;\;c_n\ge 0\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N$$

Now the following uses Newton's Binomial Theorem:

$$n=(1+c_n)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom nk c_n^k\ge \frac{n(n-1)}2c_n^2\implies$$

$$c_n\le\sqrt\frac2{n-1}\xrightarrow[n\to 0]{}0$$

and now apply the squezze theorem to get $\;c_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$ , from which $\;\sqrt[n]n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;$ follows at once.

Comment: Can you explain a little the first statement (monotonicity)?

Comment: $$\sqrt[n]n\ge\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}\iff n\sqrt[n]n\ge n+1\iff n\ge\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

Comment: where do we need $n\geq 3$?

Comment: @Groups, you can check the last, clearer inequality on the right is **not** true for $\;n=1,2\;$ ...:) You could also use some properties of logarithms or the exponential function, but you can directly check with a calculator for the first 5-6 natural numbers.